# delete the biggest number in linked list from anywhere (in C)

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int x;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void deallocate(Node **root)
{
    Node *curr = *root;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        Node *aux = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        free(aux);
    }
    *root = NULL;
}

void insert_end(Node **root, int value)
{
    Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->x = value;

    if (*root == NULL)
    {
        *root = new_node;
        return;
    }

    Node *curr = *root;
    while (curr->next != NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = new_node;
}

void deserialize(Node **root)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("duom.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        exit(2);
    }

    int val;
    while (fscanf(file, "%d, ", &val) > 0)
    {
        insert_end(root, val);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
int largestElement(struct Node *root)
{
    int max = INT_MIN;
    while (root != NULL)
    {
        if (max < root->x)
            max = root->x;
        root = root->next;
    }
    return max;
}

void deleteN(Node **head, int position)
{
    Node *temp;
    Node *prev;
    temp = *head;
    prev = *head;
    for (int i = 0; i < position; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 && position == 1)
        {
            *head = (*head)->next;
            free(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            if (i == position - 1 && temp)
            {
                prev->next = temp->next;
                free(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                prev = temp;

                // Position was greater than
                // number of nodes in the list
                if (prev == NULL)
                    break;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = NULL;

    printf("MENU:\n");
    printf("if you press 0 the list will be created \n");
    printf("if you press 1 the list will be printed on a screen\n");
    printf("if you press 2 it deletes the biggest element\n");
    printf("if you press 3 the program ends\n\n");

    int meniu;
    printf("press:\n");
    scanf("%d", &meniu);
    while (meniu != 3)
    {
        if (meniu == 0)
        {
            deserialize(&root);
            printf("sarasas sukurtas.\n");
        }

        if (meniu == 1)
        {
            for (Node *curr = root; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
                printf("%d\n", curr->x);
        }
        if (meniu == 2)
        {
            int max_element = largestElement(root);
            printf("%d max\n", max_element);
            deleteN(&root, max_element);

        }
        printf("press:\n");
        scanf("%d", &meniu);
    }

    deallocate(&root);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run the delete function it only deletes the biggest number first time and if I call it second time it deletes the last number of the list. Can someone help me fix that?

I edited it so all of the code can be seen because it was hard to understand it like I had it before

Comment: Stackoverlfow is not a homework solver

Comment: @SupportUkraine it's in the main(), I didn't add that here. the line looks like this `int position=largestElement(root);`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. I suggest co create a `main` function that fills the list with hard-coded data and calls `deleteN` and `largestElement` in a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @pipras Your complete code is not a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and without the file `duom.txt` we cannot run it. One way to minimize it would be to use a simple `main` function that calls `insert_end` a few times with hard-coded values to create a list and then calls combinations of `largestElement` and `deleteN` and the loop to print the list in order to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `largestElement` returns the largest data value in the list.
However, here:

```
    int max_element = largestElement(root);
    printf("%d max\n",max_element);
    deleteN(&root, max_element);
```

you use the return value as if it is the position of the node with the largest element.

Instead of `largestElement` you need a function that returns the **position of the element with the largest data value**.

It would look something like:

```
int positionOfLargestElement(struct Node* root)
{
  int pos = 0;
  int maxpos = 0;
  int max = INT_MIN;
  while (root != NULL) {
     ++pos;
     if (max < root->x)
     {
         max = root->x;
         maxpos = pos;
     }
     root = root->next;
  }
  return maxpos;
}
```

note: The exact code depends a bit on whether the first node is considered to be position 0 or position 1 but the principle is the same.